# Strange IConfiguration passing to Startup module

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I have a ASP.NET Core app that builds a custom configuration in Program.cs file ("Main" method.) That's how it's built:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

        // custom config file
        .AddJsonFile("custom.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                .Build();

    BuildWebHost(args, configuration).Run();
```

What happens is that before **BuildWebHost** call configuration properly consists of two parts - appsettings.json and custom.json.

When I catch execution at Startup constructor, custom.json configuration is gone: it's not there. There's a bunch of other branches in the configuration passed to the Startup ctor, but there's no custom.json branch.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args, IConfiguration config)
{
    var ret = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    return ret;
}
```

**UPDATE 2 (Startup constructor):**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.Configuration = configuration;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the properties on your `custom.json` file to ensure it's `Copy to Output` setting is either `Copy Always` or `Copy if newer`?

Comment: Yes, it's not affecting it. Currently it's set to "Build action: Content", "Copy to output directory: Copy always"

Comment: My suspicion is that your `configuration` variable isn't getting passed through, or you're not assigning it correctly after it's passed into your `Startup` class. It's not an official part of the API, but if you mouse over your `IConfiguration` in startup, what does it list for `_providers`?

Comment: There're 5 providers there:ChainedConfigurationProvider, 2 JsonConfigurationProviders (none of them is my custom.json), EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider, and CommandLineConfigurationProvider.

Comment: Can you post the constructor for your `Startup` class if it's present, and anywhere you're _setting_ an `IConfiguration` member?

Comment: Yes, see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked out why `UseConfiguration` in `Program` doesn't work, nor where it's documented when/how to use it. However, you can replace `UseConfiguration` with `ConfigureAppConfiguration` to append to the default providers list added by `CreateDefaultBuilder`.

For example:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => builder
                .AddJsonFile("foo.json"))
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: There seems to be some more info in this github answer, and I expect there is docs (somewhere...): https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1148#issuecomment-318524939